# Mi formulario no envia los datos a mi base de datos

Tags: php

TENGO ESTE FORMULARIO

```html
<form class="form-a contactForm" action="PHP" method="post" >
                    <div id="sendmessage">¡Su mensaje fue recibido con exito! En instantes nos comunicaremos.</div>
                    <div id="errormessage">No se pudo enviar el mensaje</div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="text" name="Asunto" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" placeholder="Nombre" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars">
                          <div class="validation"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" placeholder="Nombre" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars">
                          <div class="validation"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" placeholder="Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email">
                          <div class="validation"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="text" name="Telefono" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" placeholder="Telefono" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject">
                          <div class="validation"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <textarea name="message" class="form-control"  cols="45" rows="8" data-rule="required" data-msg="Por favor complete este campo" placeholder="Detalle aqui el modelo de vivienda y metros cuadrados."></textarea>
                          <div class="validation"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-a">Enviar</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
```

CONECTADO CON ESTA BASE DE DATOS

```html
<?php
 include('includes/db.php');
  $error = "";
  $nombre = "";
  $apellido= "";
  $email = "";
  $mensaje= "";
  $telefono= "";

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $error = "";
    if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['last_name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message']) && isset($_POST['tel'])) {
      if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $error = "Nombre esta vacio<br>";
      }
      if (empty($_POST['last_name'])) {
        $error = "Apellido esta vacio<br>";
      }
      if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $error = "Email esta vacio<br>";
      }
      if (empty($_POST['message'])) {
        $error = "Mensaje esta vacio<br>";
      }
      if (empty($_POST['tel'])) {
        $error = "Telefono esta vacio<br>";
      }

      $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
      $apellido = strip_tags($_POST['last_name']);
      $email = strip_tags($POST['email']);
      $mensaje = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
      $telefono = strip_tags($_POST['tel']);
      $conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_pass, $db_nombre);
      if (!$conexion) {
        die("Fallo la conexion " . mysqli_connect_errno());
      }else {
        echo "Conexion exitosa";
      }
      mysqli_close($conexion);
    }
  }
?>
```

PERO NO LOGRO QUE ENVIE LOS DATOS A NINGUN LADO, O EN SU DEFECTO A UN GMAIL, SI PUEDEN AYUDARME LES AGRADECERIA MUCHISIMO!

Comment: En vez de colocar tanto texto que hace lucir como spam a tu pregunta considera leer [ask] y agregar más contenido que de contexto

Comment: cambia `action="PHP"` por `action="destino.php"`

Answer (score 0):

> Veo un error en la primer linea de tu html

```
<form class="form-a contactForm" action="PHP" method="post" >
```

Ahi deberias poner `action=nombredelarchivo.php`

> Por otro lado, llamas `$_POST['tel']` en dos ocasiones pero el atributo `name` es `Telefono`, tendrias que cambiar eso tambien
>
> Asimismo, tenes un input para `Asunto` que nunca utilizas, y te falta el input para `last_name`, que no existe en el `html` pero lo verificas en el `php`

Answer (score 0):

La primera linea:  `<form class="form-a contactForm" action="PHP" method="post" >`  requieres indicar a donde realizar la acción, este error es muy común me ha sucedido ya en varias ocasiones,debes colocar el nombre del archivo que contiene el código para ejecutar la consulta.

Tambien se puede hacer algo asi.... cuando ocupas que se quede la vista en la misma pagina:

```
<form name="inicio" method="post" action="<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>">
```